# C# JavacriptSerializer date time issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created custom type contains datetime field and when serialize and deserialize it value of date time changed, i use javaScriptSerializer

my code:

```
  Data _Data=new Data();
     _Data.Name="Islam";
     _Data.DateFrom=DateTime.Now;
     string _strData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_Data);

    Data _NewData= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Data>(_strData);
    // value of _Data.DateFrom changed after deserialize it
```

can i solve it?

Comment: DateTime.SpecifyKind(_NewData.DateFrom, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to ToLocalTime();

```
Data data=new Data();
data.Name="Islam";
data.DateFrom=DateTime.Now;
string _strData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

Data newData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Data>(_strData);
var dt = newData.DateFrom.ToLocalTime();
```